# Make use of two BibTeX libraries in one document

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, subdividing, multibib

I am trying to make use of two bibtex libraries in the same document for my thesis:

- one for books (filename: literatur.bib)
- one for internet resources (filename: internetquellen.bib)

but on running bibtex, I always get the following errormessage:

```
Processing: Thesis.aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2010)

The style file: geralpha.bst

Database file #1: internetquellen.bib

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "unlockinandroid"

Found 0 errors, and 1 warnings in 0 runs
```

...which leaves the conclusion that the literatur.bib is not processed (the key "unlockinandroid" is in the literatur.bib ), although in my thesis.tex I have it declared before the "internetquellen.bib":

```
\addchap{Listings}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystylelit{geralpha}
\bibliographylit{literatur}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}


\renewcommand{\bibname}{Internet Resources}
\bibliographystyle{geralpha}
\bibliography{internetquellen}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Internet Resources}
```

My literatur.bib looks like this:

```
@book{unlockinandroid,
    Author = {W. Frank Ableson, Robi Sen, and Chris King},
    Date-Added = {2011-03-15 15:40:31 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2011-03-18 12:35:41 +0100},
    Keywords = {Android, Book},
    Publisher = {Manning Publications Co.},
    Title = {Unlocking Android - a developer's guide},
    Year = {2009}}
```

Any directions for solving this would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the macros `\bibliographystylelit` and `\bibliographylit`, I infer that you are using the `multibib` package. If I am correct, the following quote from p. 1 of the `multibib` documentation is relevant:

> Citations to each bibliography are
>   collected in a new auxiliary file to
>   be processed by BibTEX.

In other words, if your main file is thesis.tex, you will have to run `bibtex thesis` as well as `bibtex lit` after the first LaTeX run (p. 4). This is *not* done automatically by editors like TeXnicCenter or TeXworks; you have to use either the command line or write a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use several bibtex libraries, if you seperate them with a comma:

```
\bibliography{oneBibfile,anotherBibfile}
```